# Recorrer grid en WPF

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf

Tengo un problemilla. 
Tengo un grid declarado en WPF

```
`<Grid >
    <Grid.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF00C58F" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF00573F" Offset="0.353"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid Name="tablero" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Height="369" Margin="376,23,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="369" Panel.ZIndex="-1" Background="#FF28AC4C"
          ButtonBase.Click="jugando">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Name="casilla1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Height="124" Margin="0,-1,1,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="123" Background="#FF009128">
            <Image Name="imagen1"></Image>
        </Button>
        <Button Name="casilla2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Height="124" Margin="0,-1,1,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="123" Background="#FF009128">
            <Image Name="imagen2"></Image>
        </Button>
        <Button Name="casilla3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Height="124" Margin="0,-1,1,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="123" Background="#FF009128">
            <Image Name="imagen3"></Image>
        </Button>
        <Button Name="casilla4" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="124" Margin="0,-1,1,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="123" Background="#FF009128">
            <Image Name="imagen4"></Image>
        </Button>
        <Button Name="casilla5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="124" Margin="0,-1,1,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="123" Background="#FF009128">
            <Image Name="imagen5"></Image>
        </Button>
        <Button Name="casilla6" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="124" Margin="0,-1,1,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="123" Background="#FF009128">
            <Image Name="imagen6"></Image>
        </Button>
        <Button Name="casilla7" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Height="124" Margin="0,-1,1,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="123" Background="#FF009128">
            <Image Name="imagen7"></Image>
        </Button>
        <Button Name="casilla8" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Height="124" Margin="0,-1,1,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="123" Background="#FF009128">
            <Image Name="imagen8"></Image>
        </Button>
        <Button Name="casilla9" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Height="124" Margin="0,-1,1,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="123" Background="#FF009128">
            <Image Name="imagen9"></Image>
        </Button>
        <Border Name="fila1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"/>
        <Border Name="fila2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"/>
        <Border Name="fila3" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"/>
        <Border Name="columna1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"/>
        <Border Name="columna2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"/>
        <Border Name="columna" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"/>
    </Grid>`
```

Los Border los tengo para marcar más las líneas de separación, la verdad. 
Como véis, dentro de cada casilla tengo un botón y dentro de cada botón tengo una imagen.
Estoy haciendo el juego de Tres en Raya, asi que ahora tengo que ver como se recorre un grid para ver quién gana. Por C# estoy poniendo esto:

```
`imagen9.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(Ruta + "circulo-caballo.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));`
```

o la imagen que sea. El otro jugador pone un fichero llamado cruz.png.

La pregunta es: ¿cómo me recorro ahora por c# ese grid para saber quien gana?, como por ejemplo, preguntando qué imagen en concreto hay en cada botón... El objeto del ejercicio es saber manejar ese grid, osea, si hay una forma de recorrerlo y ver el contenido de cada casilla, tengo que hacerlo así. Evidentemente hay otras formas mas sencillas y comprobar el ganador por c#.

Gracias y un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

prueba con el código que te pongo más abajo, creo que con esto, podrás obtener todos los elementos que tengas en el grid que sean de tipo button (y que contengan una imagen dentro)..

```
int cruz = 0, circulo = 0;

foreach (var item in tablero.Children)
{
    if (item.GetType().Name.ToUpper() == "BUTTON")
    {
        var boton = (Button)item;
        Image imagenDelBoton = (Image)boton.Content;
        var origen = (BitmapImage)imagenDelBoton.Source;
        if (origen != null)
        {
            var nombreArchivo = (new List<string>(origen.UriSource.Segments)).Last();
            if (nombreArchivo.ToUpper().Contains("CRUZ")) cruz++;
            else circulo++;
        }
    }
}
```

Aquí tienes un ejemplo distinto con array bidimensional, lo he cogido de este sitio web http://www.errordesintaxis.es/verfuente.php?fuente=228

```
// ----- Devuelve "true" si hay tres en raya
static bool ComprobarGanador()
{
    bool hay3enRaya = false;

    // Si en alguna fila todas las casillas son iguales y no vacías
    for (int fila=0; fila<3; fila++)
        if ((tablero[fila, 0] == tablero[fila, 1]) 
                && (tablero[fila, 0] == tablero[fila, 2])
                && (tablero[fila, 0] != 0))
            hay3enRaya = true;

    // Lo mismo para las columnas
    for (int columna=0; columna<3; columna++)
        if ((tablero[0,columna] == tablero[1,columna]) 
                && (tablero[0,columna] == tablero[2,columna])
                && (tablero[0,columna] != 0))
            hay3enRaya = true;

    // Y finalmente miro las dos diagonales
    if ((tablero[0, 0] == tablero[1, 1]) 
            && (tablero[0, 0] == tablero[2, 2])
            && (tablero[0, 0] != 0))
        hay3enRaya = true;
    if ((tablero[0, 2] == tablero[1, 1]) 
            && (tablero[0, 2] == tablero[2, 0])
            && (tablero[0, 2] != 0))
        hay3enRaya = true;

    return hay3enRaya;
}


// ----- Devuelve "true" si hay empate 
static bool ComprobarEmpate()
{
    // Si no quedan huecos donde mover, es empate
    bool algunHueco = false;

    for (int fila=0; fila<3; fila++)
        for (int columna=0; columna<3; columna++)
            if(tablero[fila,columna] == 0)
                algunHueco = true;        

    return ! algunHueco;
}
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad,
Un saludo!

Comment: Buenas Rubén, gracias por tu respuesta. La solución me ha enseñado algo que no sabía que se podía hacer para entender mejor como funcionan los objetos en XAML, pero no lo termina de solucionar, porque ese código está contando cuantos botones tienen la imagen cruz o circulo, pero en el juego Tres en Raya esos dibujos tienen que estar en línea, y no sé en qué orden estoy recojiendo esos "children". Además, también puedes ganar haciendo una diagonal.   Voy a seguir partiéndome la cabeza, hehe.

Comment: Buenas compañero, creo que con este ejemplo puedes hacer algo mas, espero te haya ayudado!

Comment: Un tip: item.GetType() == typeof(Button) puede ayudar en las comparaciones en vez de item.GetType().Name.ToUpper() == "BUTTON"

Comment: Correcto, lo puse jejeje pero no sé porqué me daba fallo... Así que opté por la forma "sencilla" gracias por la recomendación!

Comment: hehe, usar así el grid, con indices, sería lo ideal, pero parece que no se puede, lo unico que se me ocurre es llenar un array bidimensional conforme voy llenando el grid.